# How to reference an Apache Camel Exchange within a route in Java

Tags: java, apache-camel

Within a Camel route I add a property to the Exchange:

```
.setProperty("n", Integer.valueOf(n))
```

for some `int` `n`.
If I wanted to later set another property

```
.setProperty("2n", 2*[expression that evaluates to n])
```

with value `2*n`, what would I put in for `[expression that evaluates to n]`?
I want to reference the exchange property `"n"` and not the original `int` `n`.

I've considered using

```
simple("${properties:n}").evaluate([reference to Exchange])
```

but I don't know how to reference the Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Processor` to implement this logic:

```
.process( ex -> ex.setProperty("2n", ex.getProperty("n", Integer.class)*2) )
```